# Which USB flash drives work well with Live USB?

Tags: bootable-media

Please do not answer unless you habitually use Live USB.(booting an operating sytem from USB)

I have been booting Ubuntu 10 Notebook edition with a 2GigaByte Kingston flash drive. I used the USB installer from pendrivelinux. It was fine for a few weeks, then it became corrupted. I bought 5 PNY Attache 2GB drives that will boot but will not shut down.

Does anyone know why some USB drives work and others don't? Also, do you know of an inexpensive one that works for Live USB? I only need 2GB.

Comment: Hmm your saying that if you put the same distro on two different sticks the same way, one will not shut down the OS? What happens instead does it just ignore the shutdown command and not give any errors?

Comment: Yes, I bought a 5 pack of the PNY sticks so I could experiment. All the PNY sticks behave the same, I can boot, but when shutting down the system will hang on the ubuntu loading screen. I waited 10 minutes before manually shutting down the first time.

Comment: I've always been successful with sandisk, I only use fedora and bt4 though, if your deperate you might try this http://www.avcdistributor.com/4GB-Bootable-Ubuntu-Linux-Penguin-USB-Drive-R4GPenguinWL?amp;m1track=googlebase&amp;utm_source=googlebase&amp;utm_medium=cse&amp;utm_campaign=export_feed#googlebase

Comment: Shopping questions are off-topic as per the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq).

Answer (score 2):

I use OCZ Diesel, for its speed (for 4GB, only $10 (NEW NOT USED) on ebay from seller w/99.9% posi feedback; not sure if OCZ makes smaller ones; but unless you have an unusual single-use need, it's worth that amount to future-proof it i.e. save time so you have room to grow in coming years).

IOzone says >20MB/s reads, but I have the 8GB one; I'm sure the smaller "Diesels" are similarly performance-oriented (knowing OCZ) compared to flash-sticks of comparable size.

If anyone wants a cheap usb3.0 w/larger capacity, SuperTalent Express Duo is a good way to go: (writes /// reads) 23 /// 67 MB/s, for less than $2/GB.

P.S. try UNetBootin, very simple interface & if that doesn't help, it's most likely a hardware issue.